# Cone and arithmetic progression

Tags: geometry

Can you help with solution.

Radius, height and generator of cone are arithmetic progression. Volume 96pi.
Find R, H and L?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let height be $h$

Let radius $h-d$

Let $l=h+d$
$$l^2=r^2+h^2$$
$$h^2+d^2+2hd=h^2+d^2-2hd+h^2$$
$$4d=h$$
Substituting this back gives $$h=4d$$
$$r=3d$$
$$l=5d$$
Since 
$$\frac13\pi(9d^2)(4d)=96\pi$$
$$d=2$$
So,$$h=8,r=6 ,l=10$$

Answer (score 0):

Guessed Pythagorean triplet

$ r = 6, h = 8, l = 10 $

which can be also solved by solution of three equations on Groebner basis of polynomials:

$ (r^2 h = 288, l^2 = r^2 + h^2, 2 h = r + l)$